Timefold Recommended Fit API with List of coordinated planning entities
I'd like to implement the recommended fit api into my workflow.
My domain is currently a single planning entity Task with a single planning value timeslot on it. The planning value is nullable.
The Task model contains a UUID property named coordination. When we solve, we require that Task's are coordinated. They must use timeslot's that share a coordination ID as well.
Meaning, a group of three tasks with the same coordination ID must be assigned to three different timeslot's  that share a coordination ID.
I see no way to achieve this behavior defined here: https://docs.timefold.ai/timefold-solver/latest/responding-to-change/responding-to-change#usingRecommendedFitAPI
The examples show a single planning entity at a time, and mention planning list. I was hoping to do something similar to:
solutionManager.recommendFit(solution, tasks, 
  (tasksProp) -> tasksProp.stream().map(Task::getTimeslot).toList()
);

My question is really: Is there a way for me to solve this problem, without having to run N number of recommendedFits, match up coordination IDs, and then run a score calculation on each group of matching coordination IDs?
====
I wonder if this is a good argument to making the grouped Task's the genuine planning entity. Which i've considered before, but i'm not quite sure how to achieve it. I'd assume it would require a list planning variable? Or some other clever way to achieve this.

What gives me hesitation here is that the code docs state that input tasks is EntityOrElement. I'm not sure how to determine what Element means in this case.
